# One Action multiple Store listener - Flux

Tags: javascript, flux, reactjs-flux

StoreB and StoreC listens for StoreA.action. My problem is when either one doesn't need to get updated, both are still being updated. How do I manage this dependency issue?

StoreB and StoreC only listens for StoreA while it's fetching to set the loading state. StoreB and StoreC doesn't occur on the same time.

Comment: This doesn't entirely make sense.  Actions should not be tied directly to stores, so it's unclear what you mean by "listens for StoreA.action".

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using Redux's reducers where it beats the store dependencies by having single source of truth.